# Maximum jumps in a circle to reach zero

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Alice is playing a game where she jump from one rock to the next with the following rules:

1. There are n rocks in a circle
2. Each rock is marked with a number which tells her the length of your jump
3. Each time she jump to the next rock, the number of the rock from where she jumped is reduced by one
4. She stop jumping when she reach a rock marked with 0
5. Jumps can be made forwards or backwards
6. Once you pick a direction you keep jumping in that direction

Now Given an array representing the rocks. We need to calculate the maximum path she can travel by starting from any of the possible positions.

Example Let N=2 and array of jumps be [1,2] then here answer is 4.

Explanation : Draw a circle and assume these 2 rocks on each side of that circle. Now imagine Alice is standing on the rock marked with 1. This means she have to make a jump of length 1 leaving her at the next rock (in this case it would leave her at rock 2 if she jumped forward or backward but let's assume she is jumping forward this time) and the array is now [0,2]. Since she is standing now at rock 2 she would make a jump of length 2 leaving her at rock 2 (which now would be marked as 1).
Now she have this array: [0,1] and she have a last jump from 1 to 0.
So final array is [0,0] and she made 4 jumps (1+2+1).

My try :

```
int jump(std::vector< int > o) {
    int r = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < o.size(); i++) {
        int y = 0;
        std::vector <int> j = o;

        for(int k = i; j[k] != 0;) {
           if(k >= o.size())
              k -= o.size();

           int t = k;

           k += j[k];
           --j[t];
           y++;
        }

        if(y > r)
            r = y;
   }

   return r;
}
```

But it gives 3 for explained input and not 4. Please help to find a way to solve this problem

Comment: Debugger helps in such cases.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I want some better and efficient approach also. I guess am thinking in wrong direction

Comment: Why -1 ? Do i miss something ?

Comment: @mat7 How large can the array be?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please use the homework tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have out of bound access in:

```
    for(int k = i; j[k] != 0;) {
       if(k >= o.size()) // This test is misplaced, we already access `j[k]`
          k -= o.size();

       int t = k;

       k += j[k]; // `k` may be out of bound here.
       --j[t];
       y++; // as noted, you score here number of jump and not length of path
    }
```

You may split your function in smaller part as follow:

```
enum Direction
{
    Backward = -1,
    Forward = 1
};

int jump(std::vector<int> rocks, int start, Direction dir) {
    int score = 0;
    for(int i = start; rocks[i] != 0;) {
        score += rocks[i];
        int new_i = i + dir * rocks[i];
        while (new_i < 0) {
            new_i += rocks.size();
        }
        while (new_i >= rocks.size()) {
            new_i -= rocks.size();
        }
        --rocks[i];
        i = new_i;
    }
    return score;
}

int jump(const std::vector<int>& rocks) {
    int best = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rocks.size(); i++) {
        const int score_backward = jump(rocks, i, Direction::Backward);
        const int score_forward = jump(rocks, i, Direction::Forward);

        best = std::max({best, score_backward, score_forward});
    }
  return best;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/UFpCKr)

which allows

- to be more human readable
- to (unit-)test only one jump score

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to calculate the number of jumps (3) or the distance jumped (4)?

Your question is not clear on that point.

If you want to calculate the number of jumps, you alreday seem to arrive at the correct answer.

If you want to calculate the distance, you should change:

```
       --j[t];
       y++;
```

to

```
       y += j[t];
       --j[t];
```

Comment: For [1,2,3] it gives wrong now :( . It should be 10 but its giving some other value http://ideone.com/ERVanA

Comment: You only try in one direction (forward). You need to also try jumping backwards. (Rules 5 and 6).

Comment: How to do that ? Please help !!

Comment: @mat7: You have out of bound access, once reordered check to fix that, you obtain `10` [here](http://ideone.com/PcIEK8).

Comment: @Jarod42 Rest is fine ? I am getting execution error